# Matrix super script interferes with subscript

Tags: equations, subscripts, superscripts

I'm using a simple `$\boldsymbol{X}_{\tau(t)}^+\boldsymbol{X}_{\tau(t)}$` equation.
However, the subscript of the left matrix gets "pushed" downwards because of the superscript.

Is there a way to make the subscripts on both matrices (vertically) aligned?

[image: Matrix]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$\boldsymbol{X}_{\tau(t)}^+\boldsymbol{X}_{\tau(1)}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding an empty superscript to your second matrix as well? In the spirit of `X_{...}^{}`. Or if that doesn't work, maybe `X_{...}^{\vphantom{+}}`

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE! You may use the `subdepth` package. This package is written for doing such work.

Comment: Thank you both! For some reason it did not help though. It still looks the same.